# how to get active tab URL using JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an active tab URL using js without extension. is it possible?
have tried `location.host` and `location.href` it doesn't set for my case

Note :
 I have opened 4 different tabs with my developing tab in my browser. how can I find currently active tab URL by using js

Comment: Please explain more. It is not understandable

Comment: Active tab meaning the current tab that the user has selected?

Comment: yes @UzairAshraf

Answer (score 0):

Will you please try below.

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    console.log(tabs[0].url);
});
```

Comment: getting **undefined** .. is it supported for all browser?